# Next.js 13 - SSR authentication in new app directory

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I recently transitioned to using the new app directory a few weeks back and I'm still finding my footing when it comes to tackling various issues.

I have a server function that communicates with my server to fetch the current user's details using an authorization token header.

My aim is to use this function within my app layout because I'd like to avoid running it every time users navigate between pages - it just doesn't seem efficient.

One roadblock I'm encountering is that I can't use React Context or other state management libraries since they require the "use client" directive, which I'd rather not use in this scenario.

My question is, how could I pass the user object to all child components within the layout?

I'm open to the possibility that I might not be approaching this in the most effective way, so any feedback or alternative solutions would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

*P.S.: I already tried saving the user data using cookies, but it didn't work. It said something about how I can only modify cookies in a server action/route handler...*

I wanted to use SSR (Server-Side Rendering) for the authentication of my app. I don't want to have any loading states in terms of authentication. Instead, I want my app to load with the user details already available.

Answer (score 2):

Please see if the following pattern works for you. The idea is to fetch user details in a server component, and pass user details down to a client component that creates user context that can be used in any client component further down the React tree.

```js
import UserContextProvider from "@/app/UserContext";
import ClientComponent from "@/app/ClientComponent";

// setting revalidate to 0 for testing purpose
export const revalidate = 0;

async function fetchUser() {
  return { name: "John Doe", email: "john.doe@example.com" };
}

export default async function Home() {
  const user = await fetchUser();

  return (
    <UserContextProvider user={user}>
      <ClientComponent />
    </UserContextProvider>
  );
}
```

```js
// UserContext.tsx

"use client";

import * as React from "react";

type UserContextType = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
};

const UserContext = React.createContext<UserContextType | null>(null);

export function useUserContext() {
  const context = React.useContext(UserContext);
  if (context) return context;
  throw new Error("useUserContext must be used within UserContext.Provider");
}

export default function UserContextProvider({
  user,
  children,
}: React.PropsWithChildren & { user: UserContextType }) {
  return <UserContext.Provider value={user}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
}
```

```js
// ClientComponent.tsx

"use client";

import { useUserContext } from "@/app/UserContext";

export default function ClientComponent() {
  const user = useUserContext();

  return (
    <>
      <p>{user.name}</p>
      <p>{user.email}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear this solution worked for you. Please feel free to accept and upvote this answer :)